# Can I Toggle HyperLink and TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, aspxgridview

I have datacolumn in my gridview that has either a url, or plain text.  How do I toggle a Hyperlink in the HTML?

This is what I have so far... which returns "View Link..." with or without a url :(

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" Text="View Link..." NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("DocLink") %>' Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
     <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Details") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you are trying to selectively show or hide one of the controls in your ItemTemplate depending on the data, use the `OnItemDataBound` event, use `FindControl()` to get the controls, and set the `Visible` property on each appropriately.

If your logic for Visible is relatively simple, you can add it right to your `ItemTemplate`. Something like:

```
Visible='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["DocLink"] != System.DBNull.Value %>'
```